# Python filter lambda - how many items were reduced while reducing

Tags: python, lambda, filter, reduce

Is it possible to know how many items were already reduced while reducing using python reduce lambda? If yes, how to convert this code to it?

Ex:

```
numbers = [1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5,6,-6]
new_list = []
for number in numbers:
   if number > 0 and len(new_list) < 3:
       new_list.append(number)
```

Comment: I don't understand. Please show an example of what you're trying to do, with a use of `reduce`. The number of elements "reduced" is the number of elements in the list, or minus one, depending on how you want to count.

Comment: he wants to reduce `numbers` to `[1, 2]`

Comment: Why do you need reduce at all?

`new_list = filter(numbers, lambda x: x > 0)[:3]`

Comment: Both filter/reduce would be good, but the point is, for example, if i have a unordered list with 100 numbers, with positive and negative numbers, and i only want the 5 first positive numbers, i dont want to filter the whole list and then slice it. I would like to know a way to get them without iterating the whole list, just getting the 5 first positive numbers and then return

Comment: @AndersonLuiz which is what Menglong's answer shows you how to do... (combining islice and filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's a good question, 'cause many people cannot use well of some useful build-in tools in Python.

I don't know why people downvote your question.

Here's my answer, using ***itertools*** to do what you want:

```
import itertools
top3 = itertools.islice(filter(lambda x: x > 0, numbers), 3)
print(list(top3))
```

the islice will **only consume first 3 elements** (as we passed in 3), so we don't have to worry if the list is too long, or even if there are only one satisfied number, the codes **will not** break, this is the cool of **functional programming**.

result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```